# Problm with swiper js

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I don't understand why my code is not working properly. I add 3 images to the div, but I see only one and I can only swipe one image too. What is the problem? I don’t even understand where exactly the problem could be, I checked everything but it still doesn’t work

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

</head>

<body>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
.swiper,img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;


}

.swiper-slide {
            background: #fff;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
       <div class="swiper-slide"><img src='img/h_logo.png'></div>
       <div class="swipper-slide"><img src="img/2Q.png"></div>
        <div class="swipper-slide"><img src="img/shapkanew.jpg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  loop: true,
 {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    dynamicBullets: true,

  }, 
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change class name for 2nd and 3rd image divs

You specify "class="swipper-slide"

You must indicate "class="swiper-slide"

and edit you script by :

```
<script>
  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
      loop: true,
      pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          dynamicBullets: true,
      },
      
  });
</script>
```